# Find at runtime if a library has been compiled with the app

Tags: android, gradle, module, sdk

We have an android project with libraries L1, L2, L3... having dependencies by Apps A1, A2...

Lets say

A1 has dependencies with L1 and L2

A2 has dependencies with L3

At runtime, when the application of A1 and A2 is launched, is there a way to find out the libraries/ modules that the App is compiled with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the classes are distinct between the libraries, use `Class.forName()` to see if a class in the library exists. If it succeeds, you have that library. If it throws a `NameNotFoundException`, you do not have that library.

Comment: Thanks, I understand one to achieve this is with reflection. But I am more looking at a decoupled way to find the whole module itself.

Comment: @Mallik: There is no "whole module". At runtime, all the classes are in one big pool. Also, I do not what "a decoupled way" would mean.

Comment: What I mean not referencing the class name directly

Comment: @Mallik: Well, you need the fully-qualified Java class name from somewhere. Whether you hard-code it or use a string resource or use `BuildConfig` or something else is up to you.